# Changing MainActivity in Java

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm making a toggle button which changes activity but it changes only for once but want to make it permanent so user does not need to change it again and again.

Comment: Can you add more details about how you tried to solve this ?

Comment: Use shared preference

Comment: @kgandroid can you tell me how to do that? Please I'm noob dev

Comment: Can you explain it more? It looks something simple but I don't understand exactly  what you want.

Comment: See like this : I have a main activity but I have a toggle button which puts a modified activity (for logging)  so how to make it permanent and also possible to go back

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared Preference for that . When user Toggle Button ON (logged)  into your application store login status into sharedPreference and clear sharedPreference when user click on OFF(logged Out).

Check every time when user enter into application if user status from shared Preference is true then no need to login otherwise move to login page.

To achieve that first create one class, in that class you need to write all the function regarding get and set value in the sharedpreference . Please look at this below Code.

```
public class SaveSharedPreference 
{
    static final String PREF_USER_NAME= "username";

    static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    }

    public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String userName) 
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_USER_NAME, userName);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getUserName(Context ctx)
    {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_USER_NAME, "");
    }
}
```

Now  first check

```
if(SaveSharedPreference.getUserName(MainActivity.this).length() == 0)
{
     // call Login Activity
}
else
{
     // Call Next Activity
}
```

Comment: You got it wrong by logging I mean logging steps in logcat not login